# Run go tests except from one package

Tags: go, testing

I’ve the following project structure and I want to run go test exclude option to run the test

e.g. Command to Run all tests except the test in the `cmd` package (I’ve more then 3 packages , the struct below is a simple example)

`myGithubProject/
    |---- cmd
      |---- -command
        |---- -hello.go
         |---- -hello_test.go
    |---- internal
        |---- -fs.go
           |---- -fs.go
           |---- -fs_test.go
        |---- -log
          |---- -log.go
          |---- -log_test.go
    main.go`

Comment: What's wrong with `go test internal/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hierarchy like that, you may specify the sibling folder to test (and recurse down) like this:

```
go test internal/...
```

If this is not feasible to you (e.g. you have many siblings of `cmd`, or you have many subfolders inside `cmd` which you do want to test), you may use [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to achieve what you want.

For example, add an exclusion of a `donttestme` build tag to the `hello_test.go` file (the first line):

```
// +build !donttestme
```

And then when you specify this tag when testing, files that exclude this build tag will not be considered (will be skipped):

```
go test -tags donttestme <somepackages>
```